# Ansible code to read json file to create output

Tags: json, ansible

I am new to ansible and need understading on below problem statement. Please help me with the code.

Following is the content of json file named, problem.json :-

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "type": "node1',
            "id": "11",
            "node": "server1",
            "state": "finished",
            "output": "output1"
        }
    ]

    "items": [
        {
            "type": "node2',
            "id": "22",
            "node": "server2",
            "state": "error",
            "output": "output2"
        }
    ]
}
```

We need to read the json file and and create a output like below for each respective item (ther are several items in one json" using ansible playbook:-

Check if state is finished then below output:-

```
[
    {
        "node": "server1",
        "state": "finished",
        "output": "output1"
    }

    {
        "node": "serverx",
        "state": "finished",
        "output": "outputx"
    }

]
```

If state is error, then  display node name with error message.

Comment: Fix the YAML syntax (unbalanced quotation `"node1'`...) and test it e.g. http://www.yamllint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The play

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: problem.json 
        name: test_var
    - debug:
        var: test_var
```

gives (after having fixed the YAML syntax) only one `items`, because when reading the file the 2nd `items` overrides the 1st one

```
"test_var": {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "22", 
            "node": "server2", 
            "output": "output2", 
            "state": "error", 
            "type": "node2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Given valid data. For example

```
$ cat problem.json

    "items": [
        {
            "type": "node1",
            "id": "11",
            "node": "server1",
            "state": "finished",
            "output": "output1"
        },
        {
            "type": "node2",
            "id": "22",
            "node": "server2",
            "state": "error",
            "output": "output2"
        }
    ]
```

the play use *json_query* to process `finished` and `error` state.

> *"If state is error, then display node name with error message."*

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    problem.json
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        finished: "{{ items|
                      json_query('[?state==`finished`].{node: node,
                                                        state: state,
                                                        output: output}')
                      }}"
    - set_fact:
        error: "{{ items|
                   json_query('[?state==`error`].{node: node,
                                                  output: output}')
                   }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ finished + error }}"
```

gives

```
"msg": [
    {
        "node": "server1", 
        "output": "output1", 
        "state": "finished"
    }, 
    {
        "node": "server2", 
        "output": "output2"
    }
]
```